# Cleaning up cookies whenever Internet Explorer test starts with selenium 2 php webdriver

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a set of Selenium 2 tests (using chibimagic's php bindings) running perfectly (phpunit) on firefox and other browsers that actually create a new profile each time a test is run.

With Internet Explorer this doesn't happen, the browsers keeps all the cookies whenever a new test is run. I can of course undo whatever was done in the session in the tests (logout etc) but that will increase the running time of the tests (not desirable).

What I would like to happen is for Internet Explorer to clean the cookies every time a new test is run. I tried $this->delete_all_cookies() and $this->driver->delete_all_cookies before each test but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I know you can set desiredCapabilities which would supposedly start a clean session but that doesn't seem to work. I tried

```
 $this->driver = WebDriver_Driver::InitAtHost("somehost.com" ,"4444", "internet explorer",array('ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION' => true));
```

And if I was logged in in the previous set of tests, I would still be logged in in the new set of sets.

Some help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem for IE8+ by using the IE web driver server and telling it to start IE in "InPrivate" mode.  When starting the server, use a command line similar to:

`IEDrvierServer_win32.ee /force-createprocess /ie-switches=-private`

I'm not sure what the syntax is in PHP, but you'll need to use a remote web driver.

You may also need to set this registry value:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] - TabProcGrowth = (DWORD)0`

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called reset() within Selenium2Driver.php that will reset the session, thus removing all cookies.  I just created a Given scenario step that I call before each test, which calls reset().  Here's the code:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am not logged in$/
 */

public function iAmNotLoggedIn() {
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->reset();
}
```

I know this is probably too late to help you, but hopefully it will help someone!